Error when add I18n in nextJS Page Router
I got an error when I added i18n to Nextjs 14 and used page router.
Here is my config:
locales: ['en-US', 'es-ES'],
defaultLocale: 'en-US',
When I visit the homepage, it turns to a 404 page, but when I access the following link, it returns to normal:
domain.com/en-US/about-us
What error am I getting, can someone help me

Could you please provide the code and website URL you are using for this.

module.exports = {
i18n: {
locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
defaultLocale: 'en-US',
localeDetection: false,
},
trailingSlash: true,
}
This is my config, sorry, I can provide website link for you

Could you please make sure you have an index.js file in your pages directory and also check if you have localized homepages if required.
Your project structure should look like this:
https://ibb.co/HTN4zfc

This is my directory
https://ibb.co/jf2x4SS

Could you please try to copy and place index.tsx file under [locale] and check once.

I seem work, thank you so much

It not resolse root issue, because locale in router still show undefine
https://ibb.co/Lkmr1MG
https://ibb.co/sCb8vbH

As I can check from the screenshot it is showing fetch error, could you please check in Network tab of browser if we are getting response from the fetch request.

Could you please try to copy and place index.tsx file under [locale] and check once.
